# Magento: need to cache and index on a server and not in another

Tags: magento

I have a development stage and a production stage. I would like to activate caching and indexing in production mode, and to deactivate it in development mode.

I also use a versioning system, so it could be in a config file, if possible.

How could I do?

Comment: You can deactivate caching from Admin Dashboard > System > Cache Management

Answer (score 1):

create a file clearCache.php

```
<?php
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::app()->cleanAllSessions();
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();
Mage::app()->cleanCache();
$types = Array(
          0 => 'config', 
          1 => 'layout',
          2 => 'block_html', 
          3 => 'translate', 
          4 => 'collections',
          5 => 'eav',
          6 => 'config_api',
          7 => 'fullpage'
        );
$allTypes = Mage::app()->useCache();
$updatedTypes = 0;
foreach ($types as $code) {
    if (!empty($allTypes[$code])) {       
        $allTypes[$code] = 0;
        $updatedTypes++;      
    }
    $tags = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType($code);
}
if ($updatedTypes > 0) {
    Mage::app()->saveUseCache($allTypes);
    echo "Cache disabled";
}
else {
    echo "Cache is off already";
}
```

Comment: wouldn't be better to have, at this point, a `reset_cache.php`, placed in the script of database import, that is setting the caching parameters to false in database?

Answer (score 0):

Caching and Indexing option are saved in database by default, not in the filesystem. So you can do this easily.

Just deactivate caching and set index mode to manual in the back office of your dev stage.

Comment: I need to copy the production database in development very often, I don't think that changing it manually would be very confortable.

Comment: why don't you just copy some of the tables? I don't think that you need the information from core_config_data table. What happens if you try to make an order with production settings?